# Prove by mathematical induction that exponentials grow faster than polynomials

Tags: analysis, induction

How to prove that for $\forall q>1$ $\forall k\in  \mathbb{N}$ $\exists c>0$ $\forall \in \mathbb{N}$ $q^n≥cn^k$? I should use mathematical induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use induction this way:

Assume that 
$$
q^n \ge cn^k
$$
for a certain $c>0$.
Then
$$
q^{n+1} = q^n q \ge cqn^k \ge c(n+1)^k
$$as soon as $q \ge \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^k$, that is 
$$n> n_0 = E\left(
\frac1{q^{1/k}-1}\right) + 1
$$
($E$ is the integer part).

---

Now for $n\le n_0$ and the value of $c$:
$$q^n \ge cn^k
$$when 
$$
c = \min\left\{ \frac{q^n}{n^k}: 0\le n\le n_0 \right\}
$$

Comment: Could you please explain what the E stands for?

Comment: this is the  integer part. $E(x)$ is the greatest integer such as $n\le x $

Comment: Sorry, by mistake

Comment: too bad for the 200 rep yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use induction. You fix the values of $q$ and $k$, then consider a first case with $n=1$ (which is quite simple), then you assume the following inequality is true:

$$q^n\ge cn^k$$
For some positive value of $c$. Using that, you should be able to get a value $c'$ such that

$$q^{n+1}\ge c'(n+1)^k$$

Comment: I am not sure what you want to say. You change the $c$ depending on $n$. This seems invalid. If you allow this the problem is trivial, just take $c= q^n/n^k$.

Comment: Could you please describe the second step?

Comment: @quid You're right... I misread the order of the variables, my answer is wrong then.